# glad.h giving error that opengl header is included

Tags: c++

I am trying to use glad.h with my code. I am programming on Visual Studio 2013. For some reason its giving me the error `C1189: #error :  OpenGL header already included, remove this include, glad already provides it`
Can someone help me with this?

These are the headers that I am including:-

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Post the headers again pls

Comment: If you are using GLFW, add `GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` to your preprocessor directives (or define it before including the GLFW header). This will stop GLFW from including the OpenGL header/s.

Comment: Maybe '#pragma once ' missed in top of your header.

Answer (score 42):

I just reversed the include order of `glfw3.h` and `glad.h`，like this：

```
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
```

Answer (score 10):

Using GLFW, adding GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE to Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions fixed this

Answer (score 7):

From https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

If you are using an OpenGL extension loading library such as glad, the extension loader header should be included before the GLFW one. GLFW attempts to detect any OpenGL or OpenGL ES header or extension loader header included before it and will then disable the inclusion of the default OpenGL header. Most extension loaders also define macros that disable similar headers below it.

```
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Both of these mechanisms depend on the extension loader header defining a known macro. If yours doesn't or you don't know which one your users will pick, the GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE macro will explicitly to prevent the GLFW header from including the OpenGL header. This will also allow you to include the two headers in any order.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/gl.h>
```